# how to get last element (array) in dictionary [string:Any]

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

i have a dictionary plist and i have to get an array from that dictionary which is in the last. i have to get that array in my table

```
    var dict = [String: Any]()
     
    func readAndWriteData(){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Property List", ofType: "plist") {
        var dictionary : NSDictionary?
        if var array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)?.firstObject as? [String:Any] {
           // array["hello"] = "hello"
            // i have get these value by using key of each values
            print(array)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
            dict = dictionary as! [String:Any]
            print(dict["featureImageArray"])              
        }
    }
}
```

[image: this is my plist]

Comment: You access values in a dictionary by their keys, dictionaries are unordered so what is the last item might vary from time to time.  And don’t use NS… types, use the native swift types instead

Comment: how do i give count in number of item in table section

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using pretty *objective-c-ish* API to get and parse the property list. Don't do that, use Swift native types and there is a dedicated class to (de)serialize property lists.

And there is no *last item* in the dictionary. You get the array by key `featureImageArray`

```
var array = [[String:Any]]()

func readAndWriteData(){
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Property List", withExtension: "plist")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let propertyList = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
        array = propertyList["featureImageArray"] as! [[String:Any]]
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

A still better way is to use custom structs and `PropertyListDecoder`.